# Writing results from a for loop to a column

Tags: r

I am using R to try to write the results of a for loop to a column I have created in my data frame.  My additional column is hetCSF in my data frame Genotypes and I am trying to assign it a default value of 0. The for loop should compare 2 columns from my data frame at each of 1036 rows, return a value of 1 if the two data entries are the same and 0 if they are not.  Could someone please look at this code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Heterozygosity <- function (Genotypes$CSF1PO, Genotypes$CSF1PO.1){
  Genotypes$hetCSF <- 0 #gives Genotypes$hetCSF a default value of 0 which corresponds to heterozygous
  for (i in 1:nrow(Genotypes)){ #loops the following across all rows
  Genotypes$hetCSF <- as.numeric(identical(Genotypes[i, "CSF1PO"], Genotypes[i, "CSF1PO.1"])) #decides if the 2 columns have the same value and are therefore homozygous, returns 1 for homozygous in new column homCSF.G
  }
}
```

Currently when I run this it tells me I have an `unexpected '$' in "Heterozygosity <- function Genotypes$" and an unexpected '}' in "}"`.  Thanks so much for your help.  I am very new to R so I apologize if this is a very elementary question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier approach is

```
Genotypes <- transform(Genotypes, hetCSF = as.integer(CSF1PO == CSF1PO.1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! I was not familiar with the transform function before.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same thing:

```
Genotypes$hetSCF <- with(Genotypes, as.integer(CSF1PO == CSF1PO.1))
```

or, a little longer:

```
Genotypes$hetSCF <- as.integer(Genotypes$CSF1PO == Genotypes$CSF1PO.1)
```

FWIW: Since you're new to R, the reason this works is that R is vectorized, which means that (almost) everything is treated as a vector. So you almost never have to loop through rows. Consequently, `(x==y)` will return a vector of T or F values depending on whether the corresponding elements in x and y are equal. The function `as.integer(...)` (in this case) takes a vector argument and returns a new vector with T converted to 1 and F converted to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This is so much cleaner than what I had originally written.  I am still learning just what implications working in a vectorized environment means.  I had been assuming that each row was treated as a vector but that the same did not hold true for columns.  I appreciate your help.